# Assign id by cluster in R

Tags: r

I have a vector like this

```
var1=c("A","A","B"," "," ","C","A","","A")
```

How can I create a vector of ids indicating whether they are adjacent. Like

```
id1=c(1,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,3)
```

So I want to assign ids to each clusters. Any ways to do that in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `cumsum` on the `diff` of `var1` to generate a sequence representing the clusters including empty strings and then replace empty string positions with `0`:

```
replace(cumsum(c(T, diff(var1 != "") == 1)), var1 == "", 0)
```

gives:

```
# [1] 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 3
```

for:

```
var1=c("A","A","B","","","C","A","","A")
```

This assumes `var1` does not start with empty string, to generalize it to that case, we can check the first element of `var1` and use the condition as the initial value:

```
replace(cumsum(c(var1[1] != "", diff(var1 != "") == 1)), var1 == "", 0)
```

gives:

```
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 3
```

for:

```
var1=c("", "A","A","B","","","C","A","","A")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `rle`.  We remove the leading/lagging space with `trimws`, convert to a logical vector (`nzchar`) based on whether it is a non-empty string and get the run-length-encoding (`rle`).  Change the 'values' vector in the `list` of 'rl' where it is TRUE to the sequence and replicate the `values` with `lengths`

```
rl <- rle(nzchar(trimws(var1)))
rl$values[rl$values] <- seq_along(rl$values[rl$values])
rep(rl$values, rl$lengths)
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 3
```

#### data

```
var1=c("A","A","B"," "," ","C","A","","A")
```